# Asm. How to set RC bits of CW?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm, fpu, x87

How to set in control word of FPU bits in RC to 3?

---

answer (editor's note: don't post answers as part of the question, but for now it's here)

```
fstcw word ptr cw
or word ptr cw, 110000000000b
fldcw word ptr cw
```

Comment: If you have SSE3 you often don't need this, just use `fisttp` to convert to integer with truncation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [fasm manual](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.1.13), you'd need to use `fstcw` to store the control word in a 16 bit memory location, modify the [appropriate bits](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap1.htm), and then use `fldcw` to load the modified control word.

The appropriate bits in this case are bits 10 and 11, and you want to set them both to 1, so **or** the memory location with 0x0C00 (3 << 10).

This will set the FPU to truncate all rounding and conversions, which hopefully is what you're trying to achieve.